# Asynchronously downloading and setting images inside a tableviewcell using autolayout

Tags: swift, uitableview, asynchronous, uiimageview, kingfisher

I have a uitableviewcontroller and i am trying to populate the cells (that are like Facebook posts) with images that are set to a uimageview. There are other labels and autolayout is used to define their position inside the tableviewcell.

I am using Kingfisher library to asynchronously download the images. The problem is that uiimageview doesn't know the height of the images being downloaded so it sets the image according to uiimageview height using Aspect fit. When I create a constraint IB outlet to the height constraint and try to set the height of uiimageview programmatically, still the behaviour is same but it changes on scrolling, i.e. imageview grows or shrinks in size based on the image size.

Please guide the general principle as to how to load images asynchronously inside a uitableview cell using autolayout so that the desired loading is achieved. I have no means to know the height of the images apriori.

```
        let imageArr = post.postMessage!.imageUrl!.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)

         self.postImageView.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imageArr[0])!,
         placeholderImage: nil,
         optionsInfo: nil,
         progressBlock: { (receivedSize, totalSize) -> () in
         print("Download Progress: \(receivedSize)/\(totalSize)")
         },
         completionHandler: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> () in

            self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = image!.size.height

         }
         )
```

[Main.storyboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wDgj.png)

Comment: If you don't know the height in advance, what height do you *want* to use? There isn't a universal answer to this question.

Comment: How does Facebook do it? When a user post an image, image can have any height ...? now Facebook can do a lot of processing and provide data to their app but how can we do it? In my app, a user posts an image and that is uploaded to google cloud from where i fetch it to make it available to other users and since its a collaborative project, i cannot get its dimension prior to downloading it. I come from Android background and there is no auto layout there so its not an issue.

Comment: Also I want to set the image after i set the height of the image view to be equal to image height ... but all these libraries first set the image and then let me do the post-processing in the closure -

Comment: self.postImageView.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imageArr[0])!,
             placeholderImage: nil,
             optionsInfo: nil,
             progressBlock: { (receivedSize, totalSize) -> () in
             print("Download Progress: \(receivedSize)/\(totalSize)")
             },
             completionHandler: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) -> () in

             self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = image!.size.height
             
             }
             )

Comment: You should set constant constraint on heigh and width of image inside cell. Can you provide code what you have?

Comment: @Josh height of image is the same for all cell?

Comment: nope those are all dynamic images that user will post as part of a post like Facebook posts